# How can I make user-friendly URL to link to my website with?

Tags: php, apache, url

For example, let's say my website is www.mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=1.  My account is 1, but instead of having that /profile.php?id=1, I want to instead to be able to give a link to my friends that is my name instead, so it ends up being www.mywebsite.com/chrisgreene.

I was looking into Apache's URL rewrite, but I didn't know if that was something that converted it after the fact (just a 'cover up' to show as you went to the page), rather than a hard link to use to get to the same page.

Comment: why you want to do it in apache? you should do it at your application level though imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Maybe can be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you!  I think this (found it on the page) will help me:

`code`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1

Comment: @openthgeek: You're welcome...You're right, if you try it you can rewrite the url and put it friendly....Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

in a .htaccess file in the root of your web dir. you add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ profile.php?name=$1
```

then on your profile page get the results based on the name.

Comment: Well I want this to work for all users on my website, because this will be a personal profile they'll all want to share with friends.

Comment: oh you want a wildcard that assigns the value to the apropriate id.

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ profile.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now you will get the name within your profile.php you have to search the name withing your db and use that's id.